# What version of spring-kafka is compatible with spring-boot 2.7.9? spring-kafka 3.0.5 fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I start a `2.7.9` Spring-boot application using among its dependencies: `org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:3.0.5`.

It ends quickly with a log, where not part of it is a line I've written:

```
2023-04-26 14:53:37.756 DEBUG 375289 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : Application failed to start due to an exception

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConsumerProperties.setOnlyLogRecordMetadata(boolean)'
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer.configureContainer(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer.java:212) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.9.jar!/:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer.configure(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.9.jar!/:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.kafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.java:129) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.9.jar!/:2.7.9]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar!/:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar!/:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar!/:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar!/:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar!/:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar!/:2.7.9]
    at fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.Application.main(Application.java:28) ~[classes!/:0.0.12-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[etude.war:0.0.12-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[etude.war:0.0.12-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[etude.war:0.0.12-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59) ~[etude.war:0.0.12-SNAPSHOT]

2023-04-26 14:53:37.756 ERROR 375289 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer.configureContainer(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer.java:212)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConsumerProperties.setOnlyLogRecordMetadata(boolean)'

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/web-client/ApplicationEtude/target/etude.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.9.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConsumerProperties, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/web-client/ApplicationEtude/target/etude.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-kafka-3.0.5.jar!/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerProperties.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConsumerProperties: jar:file:/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/web-client/ApplicationEtude/target/etude.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-kafka-3.0.5.jar!/


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer and org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConsumerProperties
```

So the log gives itself the solution, it seems:

**Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes**

But what are the compatible version of `spring-kafka` with `org.springframework.kafka`?

Comment: Don't specify a version, Spring Boot will automatically manage the version to a compatible one.

Comment: if you import your project through spring-boot-starter-parent, it will include the dependencyManagement from spring-boot-dependencies, which should distribute a set of compatible versions. At that version, spring-kafka 2.8.11 is used.

Comment: Or, upgrade to Boot 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the compatibility matrix: https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka.

The recommended version of Spring for Apache Kafka with Spring Boot `2.7.x` is `2.9.x`.

You cannot use `spring-kafka-3.0.x` with that Spring Boot version since it is already for Spring Boot `3.0.x` and upcoming `3.1`.